# How does a tripod attach to the (front of the) Lowepro Pro Roller x200?

Tags: tripod, camera-bag, travel

I just bought a Lowepro Pro Roller x200.  (Love it so far!) This one: [Lowepro Pro Roller x200](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0027JPW8M)

[image]

It has a strap that attaches to the top left side, and a little holster like thingy that attaches to the bottom left side for holding a tripod. This works well.

However, it also, apparently has some way of allowing you to mount the tripod on the front. But I cannot figure out how to make it work.  You can see from this picture from the Lowepro website that it is possible.  But the documentation does not help and the picture is too small to figure out what is really going on (the top is obvious):

[image]

Note in this picture there is a little "tripod icon" right below the pockets on the front.
[image]

This icon matches the icon on the little holster you can see holding the bottom of the tripod in the 2nd picture above.  The question is how does this little holster attach to the front to the bag?  There is a upside down pouch at the base of the front pocket with some velcro in it, but i can't see any way of getting the little holster to stick in place.

Anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind. Right after posting the question I poked around some more.  I discovered that there is a nylon tab, with a loop for the holster strap to go through tucked in that little upside-down pocket!

I'd post a pic (i took one) but Stackexchange's photo upload appears to be broken right now.

Comment: Answering your own questions is actually A-Ok here, it will even give you some special little medals.

Comment: Thank you! I just figured it out too, with your description, even without pics!